# Passing property delegate into Blazor component giving 'does not take 1 argument' error

Tags: delegates, blazor

I am trying to pass a property as a delegate into a Blazor component. However, I get a `Delegate 'Func<Pen, int, stirng>' does not take 1 argument` error. And uncertain what the correct syntax should be.

This is the component:

```
@typeparam TItem

<div class="MarelAutoComplete">
    <div class="MarelAutoCompleteList">
        @foreach (var item in Data.Select(Property))
        {
            ...
        }
    </div>
</div>
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public List<TItem> Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Func<TItem, string> Property { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the calling Code:

```
<MyComponent TItem="Pen"
             TValue="myVal"
             Data="Pens"
             Property="pen => pen.PenNumber" /> // Error On This Line.
@code {

   List<Pen> Pens { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the Pen class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you report is  `Delegate 'Func<Pen, int, string>' does not take 1 argument`  yet `Property` is defined as `Func<TItem, string>`.

`Func<TItem, string> Property` says I want a function that looks like this:

```
string MyMethod(TItem item)
```

Your anonymous function is `pen => pen.PenNumber`, with Property expecting `pen.PenNumber` as a string.  Is it?

Here's a simplified working version of what you're doing:

##### TextBox.razor

```
@typeparam TItem
<h3>@Value</h3>

@foreach (var item in Data.Select(this.Property))
{
 <div>@item</div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Value { get; set; } = "Bonjour";
    [Parameter] public Func<TItem, string> Property { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public List<TItem> Data { get; set; }
}
```

##### Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using Blazor.Starter.Data

<div>
    <TextBox TItem="Model" Data="models" Property="item => item.Value"></TextBox>
</div>

@code {

    public string GetProperty(Model model)
    {
        return model.Value;
    }

    public List<Model> models => new List<Model>()
    {
        new Model() { Value = "Fred"},
        new Model() { Value = "Jon"},
        new Model() { Value = "Bob"},
     };


    public class Model
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @MrCakaShaunCutis, although your solution does work, it defeats the purpose of making it generic. Example say I have multiple lists all with different properties of different types (which I do have). Then your solution will not work. But I really do appreciate a working answer, and will up vote you for that.

Comment: If I read your comment correctly, just change `[Parameter] public Func<TItem, string> Property { get; set; }` to `[Parameter] public Func<TItem, object> Property { get; set; }` and the passed value can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a simple syntax issue. When defining input functions this way, the input variables need to be enclosed in brackets.

It worked by changing this:

```
Property="pen => pen.PenNumber"
```

to this:

```
Property="(pen) => pen.PenNumber"
```

Comment: No repro on that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: The `(`  `)` make no difference. You came to a false conclusion.